# Java : Binary Search for String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, binary-search

I found some code that can be used to perform a binary search on an array of integers, and I am trying to change it so that I can use it on an array of strings instead.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.In;
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdIn;
import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.StdOut;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class BinarySearch {

    /**
     * This class should not be instantiated.
     */
    private BinarySearch() { }

    /**
     * Searches for the integer key in the sorted array a[].
     * @param key the search key
     * @param a the array of integers, must be sorted in ascending order
     * @return index of key in array a[] if present; -1 if not present
     */
    public static int rank(String key, String[] a) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;
        int steps = 0;
        while (lo <= hi) {

            steps = steps + 1;  // this will keep count of the number of steps needed

            // Key is in a[lo..hi] or not present.
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;



            if      (key < a[mid]) 
            {
                hi = mid - 1;
            }
            else if (key > a[mid]) 
            {
                lo = mid + 1;
            }
            else return mid;
        }
        return steps;
    }

    /**
     * Reads in a sequence of integers from the whitelist file, specified as
     * a command-line argument. Reads in integers from standard input and
     * prints to standard output those integers that do *not* appear in the file.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read the integers from a file
        In in = new In("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\EnglishWordList.txt");
        String[] whitelist = in.readAllStrings();

        // sort the array
        Arrays.sort(whitelist);

        // read integer key from standard input; print if not in whitelist
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            String key = StdIn.readString();
            if (rank(key, whitelist) == -1)
                StdOut.println(key);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error in the rank() method on both if statements. It states that I cannot use the operator "<" and ">" for strings, meaning that its not looking at ASCII code. How can I fix this problem? There may be other issues, but this is the only thing that is highlighted by my IDE. Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `a.compareTo(b)` i.e use comparable inteface instead of using `>` or `<` operators.

> Comparable interface. Compares values and returns an int which tells if the values compare less than, equal, or greater than. If your class objects have a natural order, implement the Comparable interface and define this method. All Java classes that have a natural ordering implement this (String, Double, BigInteger, ...).

Comment: What would that look like? Do you mean I should write " if      (key.compareTo( a[mid])) "?

Comment: `lo <= hi` would be `lo.compareTo(hi)<=0`

Comment: lo and hi are integer values, why would I use compareTo on them? Your suggestions causes an error "int cannot be derreferenced."

Comment: Sorry for that but the approach would remain the same . If your array is `String[] a`. Then `a[lo].compareTo(a[hi])<=0`. This way you can compare two strings.

Comment: Oh, so you mean then that the if statements would look like this:      if      (key.compareTo(a[mid])<=0) 
            {
                hi = mid - 1;
            }
            else if (key.compareTo(a[mid])>=0) 
            {
                lo = mid + 1;
            }

Comment: Yes precisely. Only check if you want equality of Strings or not. Use `=` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following algorithm

```
public boolean binarySearch(int key, int[] arrayToSearch) {
    if (arrayToSearch.length == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int low = 0;
    int high = arrayToSearch.length - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int midItem = (low + high) / 2;
        if (key > arrayToSearch[midItem]) {
            low = midItem + 1;
        } else if (key < arrayToSearch[midItem]) {
            high = midItem - 1;
        } else { // The element has been found
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why does your function use an integer array? I have found functioning binary searches that use integer arrays, but I am trying to modify one so that I can use it on string arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work with Strings too

```
 public static String binarySearch(String[] names, String x) {
        int high = names.length - 1;
        int low = 0;
        int mid = 0;

        while (low <= high) {

            mid = (low + high) / 2;

            if (names[mid].compareTo(x) == 0) {
                return names[mid];
            }
            else if (names[mid].compareTo(x) > 0) {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
            else {
                low = mid + 1;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```